# java.io.IOException: Permission denied with Xuggle

Tags: java, xuggle, xuggler

I am trying to run Xuggle 5.4 on a server, and have an exception I do not know how to deal with. The same code works fine on two other server, and also on the same server under another application (Playframework). The fact that it run under another application makes me suggest that that might be the fault.

The root of the error seems to be that Xuggle tries to create a temp file and the access is denied. How can I figure out where this is? As mentioned, possibly this is a location th other install has already used, and which is running under another user account.

This is the stack trace:

```
2012-05-04 08:49:01,985 ERROR ~ could not create temp file: {}
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.unpackLibrary(JNILibrary.java:274) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.loadFromClasspath(JNILibrary.java:195) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.load(JNILibrary.java:176) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.load(JNILibrary.java:158) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:16) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.Ferry.<clinit>(Ferry.java:25) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.<clinit>(IContainer.java:1622) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.<init>(MediaReader.java:137) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeReader(ToolFactory.java:77) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at logic.server.MediaCoder.createEncodingJobs(MediaCoder.java:39) [idoms-server:na]
    at controllers.FileCopyJob$ProgressListener.actionPerformed(FileCopyJob.java:127) [idoms-server:na]
    at controllers.FileCopyJob$DownloadCountingOutputStream.afterWrite(FileCopyJob.java:84) [idoms-server:na]
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.ProxyOutputStream.write(ProxyOutputStream.java:92) [commons-io-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1263) [commons-io-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1236) [commons-io-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at controllers.FileCopyJob.doJob(FileCopyJob.java:58) [idoms-server:na]
    at play.jobs.Job.doJobWithResult(Job.java:50) [play-1.2.4.jar:na]
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:146) [play-1.2.4.jar:na]
    at play.jobs.Job$1.call(Job.java:66) [play-1.2.4.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_26]
2012-05-04 08:49:02,003 ERROR ~ could not create temp file: {}
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.unpackLibrary(JNILibrary.java:274) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.loadFromClasspath(JNILibrary.java:195) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.load(JNILibrary.java:176) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.load(JNILibrary.java:158) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:16) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.ferry.Ferry.<clinit>(Ferry.java:25) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.<clinit>(IContainer.java:1622) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.<init>(MediaReader.java:137) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeReader(ToolFactory.java:77) [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar:5.4.0]
    at logic.server.MediaCoder.createEncodingJobs(MediaCoder.java:39) [idoms-server:na]
    at controllers.FileCopyJob$ProgressListener.actionPerformed(FileCopyJob.java:127) [idoms-server:na]
    at controllers.FileCopyJob$DownloadCountingOutputStream.afterWrite(FileCopyJob.java:84) [idoms-server:na]
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.ProxyOutputStream.write(ProxyOutputStream.java:92) [commons-io-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1263) [commons-io-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1236) [commons-io-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at controllers.FileCopyJob.doJob(FileCopyJob.java:58) [idoms-server:na]
    at play.jobs.Job.doJobWithResult(Job.java:50) [play-1.2.4.jar:na]
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:146) [play-1.2.4.jar:na]
    at play.jobs.Job$1.call(Job.java:66) [play-1.2.4.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_26]
2012-05-04 08:49:02,015 ERROR ~ Could not load library: xuggle; version: 5; Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem
08:49:02,115 ERROR ~ 

@6a91glkdf
Error during job execution (controllers.FileCopyJob)

Oops: UnsatisfiedLinkError
An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle in java.library.path

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.onException(Invoker.java:244)
    at play.jobs.Job.onException(Job.java:124)
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:163)
    at play.jobs.Job$1.call(Job.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:268)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:171)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.load(JNILibrary.java:161)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:16)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.Ferry.<clinit>(Ferry.java:25)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.<clinit>(IContainer.java:1622)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.<init>(MediaReader.java:137)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeReader(ToolFactory.java:77)
    at logic.server.MediaCoder.createEncodingJobs(MediaCoder.java:39)
    at controllers.FileCopyJob$ProgressListener.actionPerformed(FileCopyJob.java:127)
    at controllers.FileCopyJob$DownloadCountingOutputStream.afterWrite(FileCopyJob.java:84)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.ProxyOutputStream.write(ProxyOutputStream.java:92)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1263)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1236)
    at controllers.FileCopyJob.doJob(FileCopyJob.java:58)
    at play.jobs.Job.doJobWithResult(Job.java:50)
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:146)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: What user is this failing program running as?  Where is it trying to stick the temp file?  Who owns the directory where it is trying to stick the temp file and what are the permissions on that directory?

Perhaps you can run the program under a command like `strace` to try to see where it's trying to create the temp file.

Comment: The user is the same as the directory where Play! is running from, and is owned by the user. The problem is that I don't know where it tries to write to, but maybe a tool as strace will work. I might have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then problem is the temporary directory used to store the binaries. As the other instance created this temp location, the second process under a different user name didn't have access right.
The developers arevnow aware of the issue. Removing the temp directory or granting rights solves the issue

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue? I'm fighting with similar problem. Xuggler just can't create a file on the server side.

Comment: You have to figure out the temp directory it is using. I modified the code to put a text string out to tell me the temp directory and gave all rights to that. If multiple users, you might have to do it again after the first user has created the directory and files.

Comment: Maybe will try it, right now our back-end master changed privileges for a user.

Comment: I found the directory for xuggle temp directory is: "/temp/xuggle"

Comment: Did it work? Grand full access to write to all users, that worked for me.

Comment: Back-end master made it works. But its confusing that xuggle create some file totally out of the project.

Comment: I solved my problem by granting write rights to /tmp/xuggle to all users, as suggested by Luuk D. Jansen. I've also found his discussion with one of the main developers of Xuggle: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/xuggler-users/3RDIC7QWhCM if somebody is interested in the root of the problem. As of Xuggle 5.4 the solution is not solved.

Comment: More on the temp directory creation: the culprit seems to be:
private static File getTmpDir() {
    File tmpdir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    File xuggledir = new File(tmpdir, "xuggle");
    xuggledir.mkdirs();
    return xuggledir.exists() ? xuggledir : tmpdir;
  }

in https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/ferry/JNILibrary.java

that's used in private boolean unpackLibrary(String path) (same class). The name of the temp directory should randomized.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is quite old and xuggle has been deprecated, I thought I'd still show others how I solved this problem after looking at the comments here.

One can set the java.io.tmpdir property instead of deleting the folder or changing its permissions.

Like this for example:

```
java -Djava.io.tmpdir="~/custom/tempdir/" HelloWorld
```

---

Background:

As suggested by a comment from another answer, tracing the root of the problem back to the function that creates the temporary folder in question, shows that java uses a default location that can be customized.

```
public static File createTempFile(String prefix,
                                  String suffix,
                                  File directory)
                           throws IOException
```

> Creates a new empty file in the specified directory, using the given prefix and suffix strings to generate its name. If this method returns successfully then it is guaranteed that:
>
> 1. The file denoted by the returned abstract pathname did not exist before this method was invoked, and
> 2. Neither this method nor any of its variants will return the same abstract pathname again in the current invocation of the virtual machine.
>
> [...]
>
> If the directory argument is null then the system-dependent default temporary-file directory will be used. The default temporary-file directory is specified by the system property java.io.tmpdir. On UNIX systems the default value of this property is typically "/tmp" or "/var/tmp"; on Microsoft Windows systems it is typically "C:\WINNT\TEMP". A different value may be given to this system property when the Java virtual machine is invoked, but programmatic changes to this property are not guaranteed to have any effect upon the temporary directory used by this method.

See:

1. [JavaDoc createTempFile(String, String, File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File))
2. [Old Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/xuggler-users/3RDIC7QWhCM)